# Python - multiprocessing unexpected results

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have some code containing an iterator, which works well:

```
import multiprocessing

m = [0,1,2,3]


class gener(object):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        self.c = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        ret = self.m[self.c]
        self.c += 1
        return ret 


tt  = gener(m)

def gen(t):
    return t.next() 

print gen(tt)
print gen(tt)
print gen(tt)
```

**OUT:**

> ```
> 0 
> 1 
> 2
> ```

But if I try to insert it into a parallel process I don't get the expected results:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

m = [0,1,2,3]


class gener(object):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        self.c = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        ret = self.m[self.c]
        self.c += 1
        return ret 


tt  = gener(m)

def gen(t):
    return t.next() 

job1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt,))
print job1.start()

job2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt,))
print job2.start()

job3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt,))
print job3.start()
```

**OUT:**

> ```
> <None)>
> <None)>
> <None)>
> ```

I can't figure out, how could I use this iterator via parallel.
Can anybody help me?
Thank you!

### UPDATE:

Following @Anand S Kumar very useful help, I updated my code, and it works fine, except that the output is ambiguous, Currently I'm trying to figure out what is wrong, maybe it will be the subject to another thread, maybe Anand will help me :)):

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time



m = [0,1,2,3]
starter = 0

class gener(object):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        self.c = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        ret = self.m[self.c]
        self.c += 1
        return ret

tt = gener(m)


def f(t):
    global starter
    lock = Lock()
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        starter = t.next()
    finally:
        lock.release() 


t1 = Thread(target=f,args=(tt,))
t1.start()

t2 = Thread(target=f,args=(tt,))
t2.start()

t3 = Thread(target=f,args=(tt,))
t3.start()

t1.join()
print starter
t2.join()
print starter
t3.join()
print starter
```

Different outputs, with the same code:

> ```
> 0
> 1
> 2
>
> 2
> 2
> 2
>
> 0
> 2
> 2
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to print the return value of `job.start()` function, which does not return anything, hence it prints `None` .

Instead of printing the return value of `job.start()` , maybe you can move the print statement into the `gen(t)` function, something like -

```
def gen(t):
    print t.next()
```

And then run the program , without printing the `job.start()` .

If you want to recieve the return value from the function, you can use `Pool` from the multiprocessing module. [[Documentation]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

An example from the documentation -

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
    result = pool.apply_async(f, [10])    # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously
    print result.get(timeout=1)           # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow
    print pool.map(f, range(10))
```

But please note, you are actually creating multiple processes , not threads, they would not share the global variables.

I believe what you want is `threads` , maybe an example like below would help get you started -

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
m = [0,1,2,3]
starter = 0

class gener(object):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        self.c = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        ret = self.m[self.c]
        self.c += 1
        return ret 

tt  = gener(m)


def f(t):
    global starter
    lock = Lock()
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        starter = t.next()
    finally:
        lock.release()

t1 = Thread(target=f,args=(tt,))
t1.start()
t2 = Thread(target=f,args=(tt,))
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Comment: Yes, yes, in this case it works with your solution however I will got: 0,0,0, as result, and we need 0,1,2. Furthermore I need the return value, because I need the iterator's next value for working with it.

Comment: Then you can check `pool`of workers from multiproessing module - https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: Anand S Kumar: Thank you, I give you a vote up, but could you write some code hint? :)

Comment: But how can I get any return value from the iterator? In my real code I need a return value from the iterator to working with. It's like in this sample code we would get back the element of m[] as return value.

Comment: After the threads are over , please note, when doing t1.join, the current `main thread` gets blocked till t1 thread completes. You can crete a global variable and assign its value inside the function. Updated th answer with code for that.

Comment: Anand S Kumar: Accidentally you missed out **tt  = gener(m)** from your code. However almost done! One more little thing: When I try to insert time.sleep() into the gener class's next() method, it didn't work i.e. I got 0,0 as output. I guess it is something about the time module's import.

Comment: Where did you insert the `time.sleep()` ? Also, did you join the threads? if not, maybe you tried accessing the values before the thread had incremented the value of tt , and thanks for catching that, I was just giving an example :)

Comment: I updated the original code regarding the time.sleep() :)

Comment: I believe the issue you are seeing is because your threads are not synchronized. You can check out synchronization between threads here - http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

Comment: Anand S Kumar: I accept your answers. Your work was extremely useful for me. Thank you very much for your all efforts to resolve my issues. Perhaps can you kindly give me some hint how synchronization affect a the working of the time.sleep() function's ? :)

Comment: Ok Simple answer is, when it is not synchronized, your first function sends a call to `t.next()` but it sleeps there as the first command, before the first thread can wake up, second thread has already initiated its command to t.next() (in both cases t has value 0) , both would be operating on same data, hence both return 0 and increment the value of c. Causing the issue you were seeing. Did synchronization fix your issue?

Comment: I made a en edit on your code inside of your answer(I don't really know, if this method is acceptable in this community, because I'm newbie here, however it seemed to be the simplest way of data exchange). Unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Same result: 0,0

Comment: There was a small issue in your code, fixed it and you used `threading.Lock` instead of just `Lock`

Comment: Yes I was just wanting to fix the lock part. :)

Comment: I just ran the code, it worked for me , anyway instead of creating `lock` inside the function, try creating it outside and just using it inside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81897/discussion-between-gyorgy-solymosi-and-anand-s-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1) `start()` function does not return a value, therefore you're getting `None` to print out.

2) You're passing the generator object to each process, thereby **copying** the original `gener` object (declared in the master process) three times, once to each of the forked processes' stacks. So, even if you change your function to:

```
def gen(t):
    print t.next()
```

all you will do is call `next()` the first and only time on every individual `gener` object, printing:

```
0
0
0
```

In order to get the desired effect, you need to perform the iteration in the master process, passing its result to each spawned process:

```
job1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt.next(),))
#print job1.start()

job2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt.next(),))
#print job2.start()

job3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt.next(),))
#print job3.start()
```

Then all your `gen` function needs to do is `print` the value:

```
def gen(t):
    print t
```

And you get:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: Velimir: Thank you, The first part issue was quite clear for me, I have had some idea what is happening, however the second part of your answer is very useful. BUT: It was just a sample code. In the real code I need return value from the iterator/generator so it is not enough if the iterator do an iteration in a closed process i.e. print the iterable elements subsequently.

Comment: I need to use the iterator's result's in an other subsequent process